# How long of a duration can QElapsedTimer measure?

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way I can find out how long QElapsedTimer can be run for without resetting? The class always returns a qint64 but I don't know if that corresponds to the maximum duration it can measure.

The docs (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qelapsedtimer.html) mention that overflow occurs in certain cases but doesn't in others (which confuses me -- if you're storing a value in ms or ns in an int doesn't overflow *have* to occur at some point?)

I want to use QElapsedTimer to keep track of uptime and I'm trying to determine if its appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a 64-bit value in nanoseconds is quite some time tho'. My quick math says that (2^64/10^9)/86400 = 213500. That's the number of days. Or about 580 years. I don't think you really need to worry about it. And of course, in milliseconds, it becomes 580 million years.